# Repaint Doesnt update the game screen

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, animation, paint

In my program, I am creating a program where binary numbers fall down and players have to type in the correct value before it hits the ground. However, the repaint call does not take affect UNLESS you resize the game screen by clicking and dragging it and resizing the frame.

```
  public void run() {
    boolean debug = true;
    if (debug) {
        System.out.println("run debugging output enabled");
        System.out.println("time: " + time);
    }
    previousTime = time;
    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (running) {
        previousTime = time;
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (Number n : numbers.values()) {
            n.update(time - previousTime);
        }
        if (debug)
            System.out.println("new time: " + time + "\n time difference: " + (time - previousTime));
        try{
            Thread.sleep(300);
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
        gui.getGameControl().repaint();

    }
}
```

In the program Gui extends JFrame and GameControlGui extends JPanel

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Either you have a referencing issue or a thread blocking issue, but it's impossible to tell from the out of context code

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

`repaint()` calls the `paintComponent`. I'm not sure what is inside your `paintComponent`, that being said it's hard to say what the problem is without seeing all of your code.